# Why Anchors have bad position and seem to be inverted?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Recently I have started using Tkinter as a way for displaying with Raspberry Pi. I'm still getting used to placing and experimenting with grids and absolute positioning. However I have encountered a problem.

Whenever I use an anchor. The only one working correctly is NW. The rest seems to be inverted and centred around left corner of the screen and I have no idea why.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, NW, NE, SW, CENTER
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Style
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

gui = Tk()
gui.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
gui.configure(background = 'black',cursor ='none')

gui.geometry("1920x1080")
canvas = Canvas(gui, width = 1920, height = 1080, bg ='black',highlightthickness=0)


img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('../icons/Asset7.png'))
im5 = canvas.create_image(100,100, image = img5, anchor = NW)

img9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('../icons/Asset14.png')
im9 = canvas.create_image(100,100, image = img9, anchor = NE)
```

Here is an example. Asset7 is on correct part of the screen where Asset 14 starts behind left border of the screen for some reason. According to this image correct positioning should behave differenty [Tkinker Anchors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dov5P.jpg)
I'm quite confused what may be causing that.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: The Anchor is used to identify which part of the object being placed in the Canvas is positioned at the coordinates given.  NW means the object is below and to the right of the coordinates (here 100, 100).  NE means the object is below and too the left of the coordinates.  The NE, NW etc refer to the point on the object not a direction on the Canvas.

Comment: Ah ok, now i get it. Is there though an anchor representing starting point on the screen like in the picture or there is no option to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but does `canvas. create_image(0, 0,....)` do what you want? Coordinates (0, 0) being the NW point of the canvas.

Comment: Yeah, however somehow I thought that when I use an anchor it could be that the start is lets say NE or S part of the screen. So from there you would count it as (0,0) point based on the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to respond to the comment.

For the canvas, assuming `canvas = tk.Canvas(...)`

```
The Top Left     is (0,0), 
the Bottom Right is (canvas.winfo_width(), canvas.winfo_height())
```

The other relevant points can be calculated from width and height.  If the canvas is resized as it's being used the points (apart from 0,0) will need to be recalculated.

I can't find anything built in to 'snap' objects to the corners, mid points etc..
The code below either makes compass point wrapper functions to snap items to predefined locations. Or a snap function to anywhere in the Canvas, based on proportions.  The on_resize callback is needed, even if the Canvas does,'t change size as the id objects are often specified before the canvas is drawn.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
# canvas changes size with the root.
canvas.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

def snap(parent, id, x_fact, y_fact, anchor = tk.CENTER ):
    """ parent - tk.Canvas widget
        id canvas object id
        x_fact & y_fact: floats 0. to 1. 0 is N/W,  1. is S/E
        anchor is the anchor point on the object.
     """
    def on_resize( ev ):
        """ Callback for Configure event """
        x = int( ev.width * x_fact )
        y = int( ev.height * y_fact )
        parent.coords( id, x, y )

    parent.itemconfigure( id, anchor = anchor )
    x = int( parent.winfo_width() * x_fact )
    y = int( parent.winfo_height() * y_fact )
    parent.coords( id, x, y )
    parent.bind( '<Configure>', on_resize, add='+' )
    return id

def snap_to( x_fact, y_fact, anchor = tk.CENTER ):
    """ Returns a function which snaps to a named location. """

    def func( parent, id ):
        return snap( parent, id, x_fact, y_fact, anchor )

    return func

snap_NW = snap_to( 0,   0,   tk.NW )
snap_N  = snap_to( 0.5, 0 ,  tk.N )
snap_NE = snap_to( 1,   0,   tk.NE )
snap_W  = snap_to( 0,   0.5, tk.W )
snap_C  = snap_to( 0.5, 0.5, tk.CENTER )
snap_E  = snap_to( 1,   0.5, tk.E )
snap_SW = snap_to( 0,   1,   tk.SW )
snap_S  = snap_to( 0.5, 1,   tk.S )
snap_SE = snap_to( 1,   1,   tk.SE )

test0 = canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' SE ')
snap_SE(canvas, test0)

test1 = snap_E(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' East '))

snap_N(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' North '))
snap_NW(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' NW '))
snap_NE(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' NE '))
snap_W(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' West '))
snap_C(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' Centre '))
snap_SW(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' SW '))
snap_S(canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' South '))

snap( canvas, 
       canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' Quarters '), 
       0.25, 0.25)

root.mainloop()
```

Is this the sort of thing you had in mind?

Below is an alternative usage for the above using `snap` not `snap_to`.

```
#  Named constants for tuples of function parameters.
CEN = ( 0.5, 0.5, tk.CENTER ) # tk.CENTER is the default and could be omitted
SE = ( 1., 1., tk.SE )

# Call snap with the constants setting the three last parameters.
snap( canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' Centre '), *CEN )
snap( canvas, canvas.create_text( 0, 0, text=' SE '), *SE )
```

Comment: I get that it is the relation between objects and how anchors behave. I wanted to ask more if there is other way that could allow to snap object to right top part of the screen and count it as point (0,0). Imagine having text that is snapped to the left and you use Align Right, so it snaps to the right side. Is there something like this for the objects that exist within the canvas? Grids dont exactly work the way that would work with this idea.

Comment: I posted something over complicated two days ago.  Above edit is simpler to program, use and understand.